# Modify parent entity from within custom field formatter

Tags: entities, 8

How can I modify parent entity's output from within my custom field. I am writing a custom field that adds css class to blocks. Everything is set, except I don't know how to modify the parent entity.

Comment: Your approach is totally wrong. But you can still access the entity from a field with getEntity() method.

Comment: How should I have approached this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this from inside the field.

To modifiy the classes of the parent entity use [hook_entity_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8).

Check, if the field is in `$build` and then add the classes to the entity:

```
$build['#attributes']['class'][] = 'new-class';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from inside the field formatter.  Each of the `$items` passed into the `viewElements` method has a `getEntity()` method that will give you the entity.

```
class MyFieldFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $entity = $items[0]->getEntity();
  }

}
```

However, this is not recommended since it inverts the normal control flow. In normal situations, everything needed to render a field is a value on a column in the field itself.  Grabbing the entity is icky, but is definitely possible for strange edge cases.

Comment: I wrote a field formatter that needed to grab a value from an other field (this field could be configured on the formatter settings). This approach was a lot easier than trying to define a new field type that combined the functionality of both. Because that would also require me to write a widget that combined the functionality of two other widgets. In this case it was about a text field and an entity reference field.
Your answer was useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: `$entity = $items->getEntity();`